# Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: Relaying disallowed as tr_xxxx@gmail.com SMTP code: 553

Tags: php, apache, xampp, phpmailer, ini

> send by phpmailer Error:
> Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted. SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: Relaying disallowed as tr_xxxx@gmail.com SMTP code: 553
> Where do I need to check or edit to be able to send mail?
> Try Enable/ Disable TFA Authentication. doesn't work

```
     $mail = new PHPMailer;
     $mail->IsSMTP();   
     $mail->Host = "smtp.zoho.com"; //smtppro.zoho.com
     $mail->Port = 465; 
     $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

Comment: Add $mail->SMTPDebug = true; to check what is the issues

Comment: _"Relaying disallowed as tr_xxxx@gmail.com"_ - you are trying to send your mail _as_ tr_xxxx@gmail.com, but the SMTP server you are using does not allow that.

Comment: https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/email-setup-not-working-relaying-disallowed

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Zoho issue. Google's SPF and DMARC policies mean that you can only send from a gmail address if you send through gmail's servers. Zoho is pre-empting this by doing what gmail would do later if they did allow you to send, which is quite sensible. They could do it better by rejecting the send earlier in the conversation (e.g. after `MAIL FROM` instead of waiting all the way until `DATA`), but ultimately it's still a correct approach.

Either change your script to send through gmail's servers, or use a different from address that won't break SPF checks.